# How to show pdf file detail using php

Tags: php, http, content-type

I am using php to show the pdf

```
@readfile($actualfilename);
                        header('Content-type:pdf');      
                   header('Content-Disposition: inline');
                   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actualfilename));
                   header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

the problem is on the tittle bar it shows

[image: Tittlevar image]

and when I use

```
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
```

it prompts me to download the file and the same problem appears when I use

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$fakefilename.'');
```

This code shows pdf file in only firefox. I.E,chrome prompts me to download file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the browser's title bar text (or wherever it shows the file name)?

If so, you're out of luck here, because that won't work as it's up to the browser to decide how/where (if at all) show the file name.

However, there's some possible workaround: You could use server side tools, such as `mod_rewrite` in an Apache environment to redirect a request like `download/readme.pdf` behind the scenes to `readfile.php?file=readme.pdf`. In this case the browser won't know about the hidden rewrite and it will in fact display `readme.pdf` as the file name (even if the real file name or the script's name on the server side are different).

Comment: my header code is only working in firefox chrome and internet prompts me to download file?

Comment: Internet Explorer isn't able to show PDF as inline content by default (might be possible with a plugin though).

Comment: No, unless you parse it and send the contents as HTML (or SVG).